# How to get view's position in parent in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android APP. I customed View which is HtMarkerView and  override the view's `onTouchEvent` method. I want to get the view's position in it's parent's coordinates.
The view's layout is ConstraintLayout.
I have tried `view.getTop`, but it always return 0.

This is layout xml

```
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayoutScopeView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#FF353535"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/constraintLayoutSubRightBar"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/constraintLayoutLeftBar"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayoutTopToolsBar">

    <com.hantek.ht6000api.Views.HtMarkerView
        android:id="@+id/chaLevelMarker"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:htMarkerColor="@color/colorCha"
        app:htMarkerRatio="2.8"
        app:htMarkerType="htMarkerTypeRight" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: getTop is the way you get that.  ANd it does work.  Are you sure your view isn't actuall at the top of the parent?  Remember that padding counts as in the view, so adding padding will not make your getTop lower in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

after some trying, I use this mehotd to get view's position in it's parent coordinats.

```
private Point getRelativePosition(View v) {
    int[] locationInScreen = new int[2]; // view's position in scrren
    int[] parentLocationInScreen = new int[2]; // parent view's position in screen
    v.getLocationOnScreen(locationInScreen);
    View parentView = (View)v.getParent();
    parentView.getLocationOnScreen(parentLocationInScreen);
    float relativeX = locationInScreen[0] - parentLocationInScreen[0];
    float relativeY = locationInScreen[1] - parentLocationInScreen[1];
    return new Point((int) relativeX, (int) relativeY);
}
```